# How to write complex / multi-line hlint rules?

Tags: haskell, hlint

What's the way to match the following code-pattern...

```
do 
  x <- createModel a b
  case x of
    Left e -> throwM $ ValidationErrors e
    Right y -> ...
```

...and suggest the following replacement:

```
withThrow $ createModel a b
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
hint: {lhs: "do {x <- createModel v w; case x of Left e -> throwM $ ValidationErrors e}", rhs: "withThrow $ createModel v w"}
```

Comment: Even if you succeed, that seems awfully specific.

Comment: I agree it seems too specific. I think the pattern you're looking for is pattern matching on `Either` with `throwM` in the `Left` branch. Also `withThrow` seems specific too, if it only works for `ValidationErrors`.

Comment: Separately, I don't think you'll have much luck matching *part* of a case expression. I think you'll at least need to mention the other branch somehow. But I've never written HLint rules, so I'm not sure.

Comment: it's specific because it's only related to our project. Not to be published as a general hlint rule. Let me try matching with Left/Right branches of a case expression.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that HLint matching is expression based, whereas the rule you're trying to define is really statement based - you want to match the two statements anywhere adjacently in a `do`. It's possible HLint could be modified to do that, and you think that would be useful, please [raise an HLint issue](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/issues/new).